# REST API for multiple consumers

Tags: rest, api, architecture

For exmaple: We have a REST API which provides data for multiple consumers. The most case is like: Frontend (accessable for everyone), admin/management (for admins only), mobile app.

These ones differs in the response data which the REST API delivers. For example, in the admin request, the API should respond the email of the user. In the frontend not. Or the mobile app, shouldnt receive unnecessary data, which are not displayed in the views.

My idea was to set adapters in front of the REST API, but this won't work, if you don't have multiple domains available (e.g. api.xyz.com, api-manage.xyz.com).

I think this is a common way, which most of the app needs. I don't want to build multiple APIs to cover this case.

Is there any way on the application side, for example with middleware? Or  I know there is a role based approach, but I dont think, this is enought abstract, because the role doesnt decide which device it is.

There is a little solution: 
Role based decision which fields the user can be retrieve. Additionally the consumer has to put a header, or a queryparam like "frontend", "admin", "mobile", to identify which data will be returned. This is independent of the "which the user is able". It's just for optimization.

Are there any other solutions?

Comment: Have you heard about [graphql](https://graphql.org/)? With graphql, client gets the control over what data is returned by the api. It would mean though that you need to have a graphql server and a client too. It sounds like a good fit for your problem statement of "client controlled data".

Comment: @AndyDufresne nice to know! Does it secure also? Because a man in the middle can fake the graphQL and get data which are not made for him. I think, there comes the second implementation in action: the REST API should only deliver these field, which the user is allowed to see, independently which platform or device he uses.

Comment: You are right. Though graphql does not specify how to implementation authorization but we [could](https://graphql.org/learn/authorization/) add it. Read about the other [advantages](https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/rest-vs-graphql-418eac2e3083) that graphql offers over rest based on your business requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Your API should not know about your clients but it should offer the possibility for the clients to do what they want/need. Let's say you need to display a list of product with details. On the desktop you might bring 100 products but in mobile only 10. So the api need to provide a configurable paging. Also in the desktop you might get more information than on mobile. So here if you have an entity product, in the desktop you will get all the fields( multiple attributes for example) but for the mobile you get only the name and one attribute (for example the price) to minimize the payload size.
So the API need to be generic but give clients possibility to use it based on their needs.

Comment: Of course, paging, sorting, filtering will be provided by the API in genral.
But I think query params with fields or something like that are possible, but I also think its ugly for the client, to always specify the fields he wants go consume?

Comment: @Bohus Andrei and dothem - I agree that configuring this with the rest api makes both the server and the client implementations complicated. What problems do you see in applying a solution like graphql for this problem statement?